# Script for users to follow an Instagram account (on mobile) after hitting button in browser?

Tags: javascript, scripting, instagram

I've designed a contest app where people participate by entering their contact info. I'd like to create another way to participate by following a predetermined instagram account (we'll use mine in this example).

Is there a way to write a script so when the user clicks the "follow" button in the browser on their phone, the script toggles over to their instagram app, hits "follow" on @my_account, then toggles them back to the web app?

I've found [scripts](https://medium.com/@nathan_149/using-code-to-grow-instagram-pages-fc6b74ccfcd0) that will allow users to mass follow or unfollow, but nothing that will follow a specific account. I'd like to write the script in javascript. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: As far as I know theres no way to do that. You can open the instagram page but cant interact with it or verify the follow.

Comment: Hi @ariel - thanks for the comment. I'm seeing youtube videos (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4we6OhMJyqs) where the script follows a list of accounts. Would it not be possible to rewrite the script for only 1 specific follow?

Comment: That video is a client side script. You can only do that kind of stuff through a browser extension or a userscript.